# How to pull entries out of ldap_get_entries array

Tags: php, arrays, ldap

I am trying to get a list of users in a Active Directory group using php ldap_get_entries. I am able to connect to the ldap server and bind without a problem. This issue I have is the result I get from the array when using `ldap_get_entires`. Here is what I am using to get the data from the group:

```
$result = ldap_search($ldapConn, $ldaptree, "(member=*"),array('member'));
$data = ldap_get_entries($ldapConn, $result);
print_r($data);
```

What I get is this:

```
Array([count] => 1 [0] => Array([member] => Array([count => 3 [0] => CN=Mike Jones,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET [1] => CN=Van Smith,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET [2] => CN=Jane Doe,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET) [0] => member[count] => 1 [dn] => CN=Cool Guys,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN,DC=NET))
```

How do I pull out just the names from this array to look like this?

```
Mike Jones 
Van Smith 
Jane Doe
```

Comment: You could use explode for example https://3v4l.org/3rhko

Comment: @Thefourthbird is there a way to use sort with this as well?

Comment: You could add the values to an array and sort the array afterwards

Comment: @Thefourthbird I got it working with a array_multisort. Do you want to post your suggestion as the answer so I can mark it? If not I can give you credit when I wrote up what I did.

Comment: It is ok, it was an idea of how you might solve it. You can use it in an answer if you want. Glad it works for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Thefourthbird for the suggestion. He suggested I use the following to take out the names I need.

```
foreach ($array[0]["member"] as $key => $member) {
    if (is_int($key)) {
        $User[] = explode('=', explode(',', $member)[0])[1] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The only thing that was left to do was organize the data in alphabetical order. I used a `array_multisort` function to do this.

```
array_multisort($User, SORT_ASC);
foreach ($User as $key => $SortUser) {
    echo $SortUser;
}
```

Now all the names come out on their own line and in alphabetical order.

```
Jane Doe
Mike Jones 
Van Smith
```